# WPF TextBox: Cancelling drop operation leaves Insertion marker

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, textbox

I have a WPF App in that I want to cancel a drop operation to a TextBox, if some conditions are met (see shouldCancelDrop below):

**Sample:**

XAML:

```
   <TextBox PreviewDrop="TextBox_PreviewDrop" />
```

Code behind:

```
    private void TextBox_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        //Decision if to cancel to drop
        var shouldCancelDrop = false;
        //if (...) shouldCancelDrop = true;
        
        if (shouldCancelDrop)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }

        //...
    }
```

Problem is: After leaving the *TextBox_PreviewDrop*-Handler with *e.Handled = true* the "insertion marker" is always left in the textbox. It looks like a textcursor but is light gray and not blinking, see here (the right black one is the textcursor):

[image: Insertion marker].

**How can I get rid of this Insertion marker when I cancel the drop?**

**It stays in the TextBox until I finish another drag operation!**

So I am looking for some "CancelDropOperationAndRedrawTextBox"-Action...

Comment: The same graphical glitch can also occur when a Ctrl + V Keyboard Paste-Operation is aborted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "PreviewDragOver" event to disallow dropping the element via DragDropEffects.None:

```
private void TextBox_OnPreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  //Decision if to cancel to drop
  var shouldCancelDrop = false;
  //if (...) shouldCancelDrop = true;

  if (shouldCancelDrop)
  {
    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
    return;
  }

  //...    
}
```

Comment: I do mark this as answer as I found no other better solution for my problem. My attempts like textBox.InvalidateVisual() or textBox.UpdateLayout() for to get rid of this fuc**** insertion marker were all not successful.

My primary intention was to show a tooltip containing why the user can not paste the dragged content.

I can do this now in the function "TextBox_OnPreviewDragOver" at "shouldCancelDrop". That's sufficient for my case.

Thanks @LuckyyStrike